# What is the legal status of a p2p fee taking App for matching bitcoin sellers/buyers?

Tags: legal, cash, local

I want to make an App in the US which would help bitcoin sellers to find buyers for cash in a local area. The app would not hold any bitcoin fund, it would only serve as a tool for buyers/sellers to meet each other, and do some transaction broadcasting/verifying.

Also, I want to monetize the application, by enforcing the users to pay a fee in order for the transaction to go through. All of this without holding any funds, thanks to P2SH transactions. I would like to know if this model of application has to comply with AML/KYC rules, or if the users can stay anonymous.

Comment: checkout bitsquare.io

Comment: asking for legal advice from someone not your lawyer is always a dicey proposition. I would suggest you seek counsel.

Comment: Every country in the world has its own laws (as do states within countries, etc).  You are effectively asking several hundred different questions here.  Can you narrow it down?

Comment: @renlord Bitsquare works as decentralized organisation, and is not a company, so they can't be taken down I suppose.

Comment: @JimmySong Thanks, I will try to find someone with some knowledge about the subject.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed thanks. I don't know why I used NYK.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be primarily a question about which laws apply to financial middlemen